# Undefined method `image_will_change!' for CarrierWave on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, carrierwave

I have a simple model that mounts a Carrierwave uploader. Everything works fine in development, but I get an undefined method "image_will_change!" error on heroku.

```
class Receipt < ActiveRecord::Base
  mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader
end

class ImageUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  storage :fog
  def store_dir
    "receipts/saved"
  end
end
```

I have the cache_dir set appropriately as well according to the Carrierwave Wiki.

```
receipt.image = File.open "public/images/test.jpg" #works fine in development, fails in heroku
```

Comment: I ran into the same error message, and even though I did rake db:migrate, the error still didn't go away. So I ended up upgrading to the new Cedar stack, and it worked. I suspect though if I dropped the database, and redo the entire migration, it would have worked as well.

Answer (score 145, accepted):

It's likely that your db on heroku doesn't have the image column in the receipts table.

Comment: That worked! I forgot I modified a migration to include this string.

Comment: And, if you get an error like this when you're running rspec tests, you may have forgotten to run ```rake db:test:prepare```.

Answer (score 19):

Even after running the migration on heroku, the error persisted.

I found that a heroku restart command was required to vanquish the error forever.

```
heroku restart
```

Comment: Just wanted to let you know that you saved my life.  I was *this* close to leaping from my office window in frustration before I found this.

Comment: Wow! Found this after 30 mins of searching ! Worked for me!

Answer (score 7):

It's probably because you forgot to run:

```
rake db:migrate
```