# undefined method `attachment_will_change!'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave

I have never seen this error before, `undefined method 'attachment_will_change!' for #<Movie:0x00000106b16000>`

Possibly something to do with carrierwave.

Params in movie model.

```
def movie_params
   params.require(:movie).permit(:title, :rating, :total_gross, :attachment)
end
```

carrierwave.rb in initializers.

```
CarrierWave.configure do |config|

  config.fog_credentials = {

    :provider               => 'abc',        # required
    :aws_access_key_id      => 'abcabc',     # required
    :aws_secret_access_key  => 'abcabcabc',  # required

  }

  config.fog_directory  = 'abcabc'  # required
  config.fog_public     = false     # optional, defaults to true
  config.fog_attributes = {'Cache-Control'=>'max-age=315576000'}  # optional, defaults to {}

end
```

imageuploader

```
   include CarrierWave::MiniMagick

storage :fog

    def store_dir
        "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
      end

     version :thumb do
        process :resize_to_fit => [50, 50]
      end

     def extension_white_list
        %w(jpg jpeg gif png)
      end

    end
```

Comment: Some related links http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5481331/undefined-method-image-will-change-for-carrierwave-on-heroku http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7491595/carrierwave-rails-3-1-undefined-method-image-will-change might be useful.

Comment: According to the related links,you should be having `attachment` attribute in your `movies` table.Do you have it?

Comment: That second question answered that for me, do you want to create answer then i can accept.

Comment: Yup, missing column in table.

Comment: Well,then i will post my answer :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As i said,you are missing `attachment` attribute in your `movies` table.You have to add `attachment` column in order to fix that error.

> undefined method 'attachment_will_change!'

Generate a migration file by the following command

```
rails g migration AddAttachementToMovies attachement:string
```

It will generate a migration file something like this

```
class AddAttachmentToMovies < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :movies, :attachment, :string
  end
end
```

And then do `rake db:migrate`

**[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7491595/carrierwave-rails-3-1-undefined-method-image-will-change)**

Comment: Small typo in migration code (`attachment:string`)